# Difference between 避難所 and 避難場所

Tags: words, nuances

[This disaster response website](http://map.bousai.metro.tokyo.jp/) has a map with a checkbox that visitors can click to display all the 避難所{ひなんじょ} in the area. And then there is another checkbox to display all the 避難場所{ひなんばしょ}:

[image: 避難所 and 避難場所]

Both translate as "shelter" in my dictionary.
What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

避難所 is a building with a roof (often a school) where people can stay/sleep (potentially for a few days) if their house is destroyed or somehow unreachable.

避難場所 is an open air space (often a park) where people must flee until they are sure that standing in their house is not dangerous (collapsing, fire).

Reference:
http://www.bousai.metro.tokyo.jp/bousai/1000029/1000316.html